# C++ RoundUp like in Excel that floor's negative numbers and ceil's on positive numbers

Tags: c++

Excel has a function called ROUNDUP, which not being a mathematician I would call a true round up or at least more logical to me, in that it makes makes a positive value like 0.5 value into 1 and a negative value like -0.5 into -1. So in other words the Excel ROUNDUP do a C++ ceil equivalent on the 0.5 value, and C++ floor equivalent on the -0.5 value.

Is there nothing built into C++ like that? Yes I know I can make my own function, but that defeats the reason I need this as a custom function that determines if number to be rounded is a positive or a negative, then needs an IF statement!

Comment: *"needs an IF statement!"* How many programs have you written that completely avoided any `if` statements? Do you think `if` statements have cooties? Anyway, in case you have some kind of if-o-phobia, you can write that function using a condition operator `?:`

Comment: I don't want to use two different functions for different numbers, that being positive or negative. I need one function that rounds away from zero, that has no IF statements.

Comment: `0.1` should round to `1.0` and `-0.1` should round to `-1.0`?

Comment: Geez! @Igor Tandetnik I am doing real-time sensitive audio coding, so IF's are EXPENSIVE!!!

Comment: Well, there's no magic. If there were a library function doing what you want, it'd have an `if` statement in its implementation. `floor` and `ceil` likely have an `if` statement in their implementations.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes sir, exactly what I need.

Comment: `double roundup(double x) { return std::ceil(std::abs(x)) * (1 - std::signbit(x) * 2); }` does it.

Comment: my stupid homework detector is going to 11. "implement a function that does what ROUNDUP does, but without using 'if'"

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thanks for the solution, however in my case it is slower than using an IF statement. Yours was actually faster about 10% faster than 1201ProgramAlarm's solution and doing some more accurate tests, your implementations in my setup, is actually MUCH slower than I originally reported/

Comment: I didn't expect it to be faster, just to satisfy the "not using `if`" requirement. Like I said, there's no magic - even if the code you write doesn't branch, code inside those library functions does. Plus you throw a bunch of arithmetic on top.

Answer (score 0):

There's not built in function to round away from zero.  But you can write your own without any obvious `if` statements.

```
double RoundAwayFromZero(double v) {
    auto s = std::copysign(1.0, v);
    return s * std::ceil(v * s);
}
```

This uses [`copysign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/copysign) to get a properly signed 1.0 value that is then used to make the value positive, round it away from 0 using [`ceil`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil), then restore the proper sign to the result.

Comment: Thank's for your solution. I did try and implement it, compiled to release, and did some time tests. Unfortunately in my case, this code is actually a tiny bit slower, about 1%, than my original code containing one IF statement, but thanks a lot. I suspect Igor's will be about the same.